# Are degrees of freedom in lmerTest::anova correct? They are very different from RM-ANOVA

Tags: anova, mixed-model, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme, degrees-of-freedom

I am analyzing the results of a reaction time experiment in R.

I ran a repeated measures ANOVA (1 within-subject factor with 2 levels and 1 between-subject factor with 2 levels). I ran a similar linear mixed model and I wanted to summarize the lmer results in the form of ANOVA table using `lmerTest::anova`.

Don't get me wrong: I did not expect the identical results, however I am not sure about the degrees of freedom in `lmerTest::anova` results. <strike>It seems to me it rather reflects an ANOVA with no aggregation on subject-level.</strike>

I am aware of the fact that calculating degrees of freedom in mixed-effect models is tricky, but `lmerTest::anova` is mentioned as one possible solution in the updated `?pvalues` topic (`lme4` package).

Is this calculation correct? Do the results of `lmerTest::anova` correctly reflect the specified model?

**Update:** I made the individual differences larger. The degrees of freedom in `lmerTest::anova` are more different from simple anova, but I am still not sure, why they are so large for the within-subject factor/interaction.

```
# mini example with ANT dataset from ez package
library(ez); library(lme4); library(lmerTest)

# repeated measures ANOVA with ez package
data(ANT)
ANT.2 <- subset(ANT, !error)
# update: make individual differences larger
baseline.shift <- rnorm(length(unique(ANT.2$subnum)), 0, 50)
ANT.2$rt <- ANT.2$rt + baseline.shift[as.numeric(ANT.2$subnum)]

anova.ez <- ezANOVA(data = ANT.2, dv = .(rt), wid = .(subnum), 
  within = .(direction), between = .(group))
anova.ez

# similarly with lmer and lmerTest::anova
model <- lmer(rt ~ group * direction + (1 | subnum), data = ANT.2)
lmerTest::anova(model)

# simple ANOVA on all available data
m <- lm(rt ~ group * direction, data = ANT.2)
anova(m)
```

Results of the code above [**updated**]:

**anova.ez**

$ANOVA

```
           Effect DFn DFd         F          p p<.05          ges
2           group   1  18 2.6854464 0.11862957       0.1294475137
3       direction   1  18 0.9160571 0.35119193       0.0001690471
4 group:direction   1  18 4.9169156 0.03970473     * 0.0009066868
```

**lmerTest::anova(model)**

```
Analysis of Variance Table of type 3  with  Satterthwaite 
approximation for degrees of freedom
                Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Denom Pr(>F)
group            1  13293   13293  2.6830    18 0.1188
direction        1   1946    1946  0.3935  5169 0.5305
group:direction  1  11563   11563  2.3321  5169 0.1268
```

**anova(m)**

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: rt
                  Df   Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value Pr(>F)    
group              1  1791568 1791568 242.3094 <2e-16 ***
direction          1      728     728   0.0985 0.7537    
group:direction    1    12024   12024   1.6262 0.2023    
Residuals       5187 38351225    7394                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I *think* that `lmerTest` is getting it right and `ezanova` is getting it wrong in this case.

- the results from `lmerTest` agree with my intuition/understanding
- two different computations in `lmerTest` (Satterthwaite and Kenward-Roger) agree
- they also agree with `nlme::lme`
- when I run it, `ezanova` gives a warning, which I don't entirely understand, but which should not be disregarded ...

Re-running example:

```
library(ez); library(lmerTest); library(nlme)
data(ANT)
ANT.2 <- subset(ANT, !error)
set.seed(101)  ## for reproducibility
baseline.shift <- rnorm(length(unique(ANT.2$subnum)), 0, 50)
ANT.2$rt <- ANT.2$rt + baseline.shift[as.numeric(ANT.2$subnum)]
```

Figure out experimental design

```
with(ANT.2,table(subnum,group,direction))
```

So it looks like individuals (`subnum`) are placed in either control or treatment groups, and each is tested for both directions -- i.e. direction can be tested within individuals (denominator df is large), but group and group:direction can only be tested among individuals

```
(anova.ez <- ezANOVA(data = ANT.2, dv = .(rt), wid = .(subnum), 
    within = .(direction), between = .(group)))
## $ANOVA
##            Effect DFn DFd         F          p p<.05          ges
## 2           group   1  18 2.4290721 0.13651174       0.1183150147
## 3       direction   1  18 0.9160571 0.35119193       0.0002852171
## 4 group:direction   1  18 4.9169156 0.03970473     * 0.0015289914
```

Here I get `Warning: collapsing data to cell means.  *IF* the requested effects are a subset of the full design, you must use the "within_full" argument, else results may be inaccurate.`  The denominator DF look a little funky (all equal to 18): I think they should be larger for direction and group:direction, which can be tested independently (but would be smaller if you added `(direction|subnum)` to the model)?

```
# similarly with lmer and lmerTest::anova
model <- lmer(rt ~ group * direction + (1 | subnum), data = ANT.2)
lmerTest::anova(model)
##                 Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Denom Pr(>F)
## group            1 12065.7 12065.7  2.4310    18 0.1364
## direction        1  1952.2  1952.2  0.3948  5169 0.5298
## group:direction  1 11552.2 11552.2  2.3299  5169 0.1270
```

the `Df` column here refers to the numerator df, `Denom` (second-to-last) gives the estimated denominator df; they agree with the classical intuition.  More important, we also get different answers for the F values ...

We can also double-check with Kenward-Roger (*very* slow because it involves refitting the model several times)

```
lmerTest::anova(model,ddf="Kenward-Roger")
```

The results are identical.

For this example `lme` (from the `nlme` package) actually does a perfectly good job guessing the appropriate denominator df (the F and p-values are very slightly different):

```
model3 <- lme(rt ~ group * direction, random=~1|subnum, data = ANT.2)
anova(model3)[-1,]
##                 numDF denDF   F-value p-value
## group               1    18 2.4334314  0.1362
## direction           1  5169 0.3937316  0.5304
## group:direction     1  5169 2.3298847  0.1270
```

---

If I fit an interaction between `direction` and `subnum` the df for `direction` and `group:direction` are much smaller (I would have thought they would be 18, but maybe I'm getting something wrong):

```
model2 <- lmer(rt ~ group * direction + (direction | subnum), data = ANT.2)
lmerTest::anova(model2)
##                 Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Denom Pr(>F)
## group            1 20334.7 20334.7  2.4302  17.995 0.1364
## direction        1  1804.3  1804.3  0.3649 124.784 0.5469
## group:direction  1 10616.6 10616.6  2.1418 124.784 0.1459
```

Comment: Thank you @Ben Bolker for your answer. I will think over your comments and make few more experiments. I understand the `ezAnova` warning as you should not run 2x2 anova if in fact your data are from 2x2x2 design.

Comment: Possibly the warning that comes with `ez` could be re-worded; it actually has two parts that are important: (1) that data is being aggregated and (2) stuff about partial designs. #1 is most pertinent to the discrepancy as it explains that in order to do a traditional non-mixed-effects anova, one must aggregate the data to a single observation per cell of the design. In this case, we want one observation per subject per level of the "direction" variable (whilst maintaining group labels for subjects). ezANOVA computes this automatically.

Comment: +1 but I am not sure that ezanova has it wrong. I ran `summary(aov(rt ~ group*direction + Error(subnum/direction), data=ANT.2))` and it gives 16 (?) dfs for `group` and 18 for `direction` and `group:direction`. The fact that there are ~125 observations per group/direction combination is pretty much irrelevant for RM-ANOVA, see e.g. my own question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/286280: direction is tested, so-to-say, against subject-direction interaction.

Comment: Ben, following up on my previous comment: is it actually what you meant with "I would have thought they would be 18, but maybe I'm getting something wrong"? If so, then we are in agreement. But again, 18 agrees with RM-ANOVA and disagrees with `lmerTest` that estimates ~125 dfs.

Comment: Update to the above: `lmerTest::anova(model2, ddf="Kenward-Roger")` returns 18.000 df for `group` and `17.987` df for the other two factors, which is in excellent agreement with RM-ANOVA (as per ezAnova). My conclusion is that Satterthwaite's approximation fails for `model2` for some reason.

Answer (score 11):

I generally agree with Ben's analysis but let me add a couple of remarks and
a little intuition.

First, the overall results:

1. lmerTest results using the Satterthwaite method are correct
2. The Kenward-Roger method is also correct and agrees with Satterthwaite

Ben outlines the design in which `subnum` is nested in `group` while `direction`
and `group:direction` are crossed with `subnum`. This means that the natural
error term (i.e. the so-called "enclosing error stratum")
for `group` is `subnum` while the enclosing error stratum for the
other terms (including `subnum`) is the residuals.

This structure can be represented in a so-called factor-structure diagram:

```
names <- c(expression("[I]"[5169]^{5191}),
           expression("[subnum]"[18]^{20}), expression(grp:dir[1]^{4}),
           expression(dir[1]^{2}), expression(grp[1]^{2}), expression(0[1]^{1}))
x <- c(2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8)
y <- c(5, 7, 5, 3, 7, 5)
plot(NA, NA, xlim=c(2, 8), ylim=c(2, 8), type="n", axes=F, xlab="", ylab="")
text(x, y, names) # Add text according to ’names’ vector
# Define coordinates for start (x0, y0) and end (x1, y1) of arrows:
x0 <- c(1.8, 1.8, 4.2, 4.2, 4.2, 6, 6) + .5
y0 <- c(5, 5, 7, 5, 5, 3, 7)
x1 <- c(2.7, 2.7, 5, 5, 5, 7.2, 7.2) + .5
y1 <- c(5, 7, 7, 3, 7, 5, 5)
arrows(x0, y0, x1, y1, length=0.1)
```

[image: Factor structure diagram]

Here random terms are enclosed in brackets, `0` represents the overall mean
(or intercept), `[I]` represents the error term, the super-script numbers are
the number of levels and the sub-script numbers are the number of degrees of
freedom assuming a balanced design. The diagram indicates that the natural
error term (enclosing error stratum) for `group` is `subnum` and
that the numerator df for `subnum`, which equals the denominator df for `group`,
is 18: 20 minus 1 df for `group` and 1 df for the overall mean. A more comprehensive introduction to factor structure diagrams is available in chapter 2 here: https://02429.compute.dtu.dk/eBook.

If the data were exactly balanced we would be able to construct the F-tests from
a SSQ-decomposition as provided by `anova.lm`. Since the dataset is very-closely balanced we can obtain approximate F-tests as follows:

```
ANT.2 <- subset(ANT, !error)
set.seed(101)
baseline.shift <- rnorm(length(unique(ANT.2$subnum)), 0, 50)
ANT.2$rt <- ANT.2$rt + baseline.shift[as.numeric(ANT.2$subnum)]
fm <- lm(rt ~ group * direction + subnum, data=ANT.2)
(an <- anova(fm))
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: rt
                  Df   Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value Pr(>F)    
group              1   994365  994365 200.5461 <2e-16 ***
direction          1     1568    1568   0.3163 0.5739    
subnum            18  7576606  420923  84.8927 <2e-16 ***
group:direction    1    11561   11561   2.3316 0.1268    
Residuals       5169 25629383    4958                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Here all *F* and *p* values are computed assuming that all terms have the residuals as their enclosing error stratum, and that is true for all but 'group'. The 'balanced-correct' *F*-test for group is instead:

```
F_group <- an["group", "Mean Sq"] / an["subnum", "Mean Sq"]
c(Fvalue=F_group, pvalue=pf(F_group, 1, 18, lower.tail = FALSE))
   Fvalue    pvalue 
2.3623466 0.1416875
```

where we use the `subnum` MS instead of the `Residuals` MS in the *F*-value
denominator.

Note that these values match quite well with the Satterthwaite results:

```
model <- lmer(rt ~ group * direction + (1 | subnum), data = ANT.2)
anova(model, type=1)
Type I Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
                 Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value Pr(>F)
group           12065.3 12065.3     1    18  2.4334 0.1362
direction        1951.8  1951.8     1  5169  0.3936 0.5304
group:direction 11552.2 11552.2     1  5169  2.3299 0.1270
```

Remaining differences are due to the data not being exactly balanced.

The OP compares `anova.lm` with `anova.lmerModLmerTest`, which is ok, but to compare like with like we have to use the same contrasts.
In this case there is a difference between `anova.lm` and `anova.lmerModLmerTest` since they produce Type I and III tests by default respectively, and for this dataset there is a
(small) difference between the Type I and III contrasts:

```
show_tests(anova(model, type=1))$group
               (Intercept) groupTreatment directionright groupTreatment:directionright
groupTreatment           0              1    0.005202759                     0.5013477

show_tests(anova(model, type=3))$group # type=3 is default
               (Intercept) groupTreatment directionright groupTreatment:directionright
groupTreatment           0              1              0                           0.5
```

If the data set had been completely balanced the type I contrasts would have
been the same as the type III contrasts (which are not affected by the observed
number of samples).

One last remark is that the 'slowness' of the Kenward-Roger method is not due to
model re-fitting, but because it involves computations with the marginal
variance-covariance matrix of the observations/residuals (5191x5191 in this case)
which is not the case for Satterthwaite's method.

## Concerning model2

As for model2 the situation becomes more complex and I think it is easier to
start the discussion with another model where I have included the
'classical' interaction between `subnum` and `direction`:

```
model3 <- lmer(rt ~ group * direction + (1 | subnum) +
                 (1 | subnum:direction), data = ANT.2)
VarCorr(model3)
 Groups           Name        Std.Dev.  
 subnum:direction (Intercept) 1.7008e-06
 subnum           (Intercept) 4.0100e+01
 Residual                     7.0415e+01
```

Because the variance associated with the interaction is essentially zero (in the
presence of the `subnum` random main-effect) the interaction
term has no effect on the calculation of denominator degrees of freedom, *F*-values and *p*-values:

```
anova(model3, type=1)
Type I Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
                 Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value Pr(>F)
group           12065.3 12065.3     1    18  2.4334 0.1362
direction        1951.8  1951.8     1  5169  0.3936 0.5304
group:direction 11552.2 11552.2     1  5169  2.3299 0.1270
```

However, `subnum:direction` is the enclosing error stratum for `subnum` so if
we remove `subnum` all the associated SSQ falls back into `subnum:direction`

```
model4 <- lmer(rt ~ group * direction +
                 (1 | subnum:direction), data = ANT.2)
```

Now the natural error term for `group`, `direction` and `group:direction` is
`subnum:direction` and with `nlevels(with(ANT.2, subnum:direction))` = 40 and
four parameters the denominator degrees of freedom for those terms should be
about 36:

```
anova(model4, type=1)
Type I Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
                 Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F value  Pr(>F)  
group           24004.5 24004.5     1 35.994  4.8325 0.03444 *
direction          50.6    50.6     1 35.994  0.0102 0.92020  
group:direction   273.4   273.4     1 35.994  0.0551 0.81583  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

These *F*-tests can also be approximated with the 'balanced-correct' *F*-tests:

```
an4 <- anova(lm(rt ~ group*direction + subnum:direction, data=ANT.2))
an4[1:3, "F value"] <- an4[1:3, "Mean Sq"] / an4[4, "Mean Sq"]
an4[1:3, "Pr(>F)"] <- pf(an4[1:3, "F value"], 1, 36, lower.tail = FALSE)
an4
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: rt
                   Df   Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
group               1   994365  994365  4.6976 0.0369 *  
direction           1     1568    1568  0.0074 0.9319    
group:direction     1    10795   10795  0.0510 0.8226    
direction:subnum   36  7620271  211674 42.6137 <2e-16 ***
Residuals        5151 25586484    4967                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

now turning to model2:

```
model2 <- lmer(rt ~ group * direction + (direction | subnum), data = ANT.2)
```

This model describes a rather complicated random-effect covariance structure
with a 2x2 variance-covariance matrix.
The default parameterization is not easy
to deal with and we are better of with a re-parameterization of the model:

```
model2 <- lmer(rt ~ group * direction + (0 + direction | subnum), data = ANT.2)
```

If we compare `model2` to `model4`, they have equally many random-effects; 2 for
each `subnum`, i.e. 2*20=40 in total. While `model4` stipulates a single variance
parameter for all 40 random effects, `model2` stipulates that each `subnum`-pair of random effects has a bi-variate normal distribution with a 2x2 variance-covariance matrix the parameters of which are given by

```
VarCorr(model2)
 Groups   Name           Std.Dev. Corr 
 subnum   directionleft  38.880        
          directionright 41.324   1.000
 Residual                70.405
```

This indicates over-fitting, but let's save that for another day. The important point here is that `model4` is a special-case of `model2` *and* that `model` is *also* a special case of `model2`. Loosely (and intuitively) speaking `(direction | subnum)` contains or captures the variation associated with the main effect `subnum` *as well as* the interaction `direction:subnum`. In terms of the random effects we can think of these two effects or structures as capturing variation between rows and rows-by-columns respectively:

```
head(ranef(model2)$subnum)
  directionleft directionright
1    -25.453576     -27.053697
2     16.446105      17.479977
3    -47.828568     -50.835277
4     -1.980433      -2.104932
5      5.647213       6.002221
6     41.493591      44.102056
```

In this case these random effect estimates as well as the variance parameter
estimates both indicate that we really only have a random main effect
of `subnum` (variation between rows) present here.
What this all leads up to is that Satterthwaite denominator degrees of freedom in

```
anova(model2, type=1)
Type I Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
                 Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF   DenDF F value Pr(>F)
group           12059.8 12059.8     1  17.998  2.4329 0.1362
direction        1803.6  1803.6     1 125.135  0.3638 0.5475
group:direction 10616.6 10616.6     1 125.136  2.1418 0.1458
```

is a compromise between these main-effect and interaction structures: The group
DenDF remains at 18 (nested in `subnum` by design) but the `direction` and
`group:direction` DenDF are compromises between 36 (`model4`) and 5169
(`model`).

I don't think anything here indicates that the Satterthwaite approximation (or its implementation in **lmerTest**) is faulty.

The equivalent table with the Kenward-Roger method gives

```
anova(model2, type=1, ddf="Ken")
Type I Analysis of Variance Table with Kenward-Roger's method
                 Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F value Pr(>F)
group           12059.8 12059.8     1 18.000  2.4329 0.1362
direction        1803.2  1803.2     1 17.987  0.3638 0.5539
group:direction 10614.7 10614.7     1 17.987  2.1414 0.1606
```

It is not surprising that KR and Satterthwaite can differ but for all practical purposes the difference in *p*-values is minute. My analysis above indicates that the `DenDF` for `direction` and `group:direction` should not be smaller than ~36 and probably larger than that given that we basically only have the random main effect of `direction` present, so if anything I think this is an indication that the KR method gets the `DenDF` too low in this case. But keep in mind that the data don't really support the `(group | direction)` structure so the comparison is a little artificial - it would be more interesting if the model was actually supported.

Comment: +6, thanks, very interesting! A couple of questions. (1) Where can I read more about "enclosing error stratum"? I googled this term and this answer was the *only* hit. More generally, what literature would you recommend to learn about these issues? (2a) As far I understand, classical RM-ANOVA for this design corresponds to your `model3`. However, it uses `subnum:direction` as the error term for testing `direction`. Whereas here you can force this to happen only by excluding `(1|subnum)` as in `model4`. Why? (2b) Also, RM-ANOVA yields df=18 for `direction`, not 36 as you get in `model4`. Why?

Comment: For my points (2a+2b), see `summary(aov(rt ~ group*direction + Error(subnum/direction), data=ANT.2))`.

Comment: (1) The topic of error strata and which terms are enclosed in which strata are derived from the Expected Mean Square expressions for a given model/design. This is "standard" Design of Experiments (DoE) material though these more technical topics are often dropped in easy-going ("applied") variants of such courses. See for example ch 11&12 in http://users.stat.umn.edu/~gary/book/fcdae.pdf for an introduction. I learned the topic from D C Montgomery's equivalent text and the extensive extra materials from the (recently and regrettably) late Professor Henrik Spliid.

Comment: ... For a more thorough treatment Variance Components (1992 and 2006) by Searle et al is a classic.

Comment: Ahh, yes, I should have seen that: if we have a model in which both `subnum` and `subnum:direction` are non-zero then `anova(lm(rt2 ~ group * direction + subnum + subnum:direction, data = ANT.2))` 
gives 18 df for all three factors and this is what the KR-method picks up.
This can be seen already with `model3` where KR gives the design-based 18 df for all terms _even_ when the interaction variance is zero while Satterthwaite recognizes the vanishing variance term and adjusts the df accordingly....

Comment: ... If the interaction variance is non-zero both methods give 18 df for all three terms - the same is true for model2.
The difference in how zero-variance terms are handled may be inherent method differences or 'just' implementation differences.

Comment: RM-ANOVA is in my experience one of the more ambiguous terms in statistics. In this design we do not (I assume) have the restriction on randomization that is present with the 'time' variable in RM-ANOVAs. Sometimes the F-tests are adjusted for such randomization restrictions as is also done in split-plot designs. I am not familiar with how `aov` constructs its tests but it may (1) assume a different design, or (2) adjust its tests under the assumption of restrictions on the randomization. I would not be surprised if the `Error()` capabilities in `aov` were made for split-plot designs.

Comment: Hmm. I don't quite know what you mean by "the restriction on randomization", but I was under impression that a design with one between-subject factor (`group`) and one within-subject factor (`direction`) *is* exactly the same thing as split-plot design. In fact, I've definitely seen this explicitly stated in different places on our forum and elsewhere online. Is it not the case?!

Comment: No, a defining feature about split-plot designs is different levels of randomization or the restrictions on the randomization scheme. It is not enough to look at the data structure; you have to know how the randomization was done. See chapter 16 in the book I linked to above.

Comment: Hmm. I read the section 16.1. Now I understand what the "restriction on radomization" refers to. However, I still don't see why this design is not a split-plot. Subjects are randomly assigned to the two groups (subjects are whole plots). And each subject experiences two directions, presumably in random order. So here are two randomizations, exactly as in the split-plot; and there is the same "restriction". It still seems to me that it's a split-plot. Perhaps you meant that if the time order of the within-subject factor levels is not randomized *then* it's not a split-plot; that's a good point.

Comment: I have awarded the bounty to this answer now, but I would still be very interested in clarifying this issue about split-plot.