# Satterthwaite vs. Kenward-Roger approximations for the degrees of freedom in mixed models

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, degrees-of-freedom

The `lmerTest` package provides an `anova()` function for linear mixed models with optionally Satterthwaite's (default) or Kenward-Roger's approximation of the degrees of freedom (df). What is the difference between these two approaches? When to choose which?

Comment: See the companion paper [Kuznetsova et al, 2017, lmerTest Package: Tests in Linear Mixed Effects Models](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v082i13/v82i13).

Comment: In the Discussion they say "From our practice, we observed that the
p
values that the approximation methods
provide  are  generally  very  close  to  each  other.   Schaalje,  McBride,  and  Fellingham  (2002)
performed  a  number  of  simulations  in  order  to  investigate  the  appropriateness  of  the  approximation methods.  They discovered that complexity of the covariance structures, sample
size and imbalance affect the performance of both approximations.  However,  these factors
affect the Satterthwaite’s method more than the Kenward-Roger’s."

Comment: Two examples where KR gives more appropriate dfs than Satterthwaite: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/320895 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84268.

Comment: Another example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331541.

Comment: The article [Evaluating significance in linear mixed-effects models in R by Steven G. Luke](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758%2Fs13428-016-0809-y) has some nice comparisons of these methods. It concludes that both KR and Satterthwaite derived from REML models produce acceptable Type I error rates even for smaller samples.

Answer (score 9):

I'm also interested in figuring out what the difference might be. The best I can offer you, for now, is that [this blog post](http://mindingthebrain.blogspot.com/2014/02/three-ways-to-get-parameter-specific-p.html) suggests that the Kenward-Roger approximation is slightly, but probably not significantly, more conservative than the Satterthwaite approximation. The author also notes that they are both more conservative than the normal approximation, but again, not by much if the sample size is high enough. I'm not sure whether or not this was a generalizable conclusion of the author's or not though.

Edit: I will add that the article *"A comparison of denominator degrees of freedom approximation methods in the unbalanced two-way factorial mixed model"* by K.B. Gregory seems to indicate that neither method is typically a better method, although there are apparently occasions where the Kenward-Roger approximation loses some level of conservativeness.

Comment: it's *Kenward-Roger* (no "s") ... Kenward-Roger's if you insist ... but usually expressed without the 's ... see also http://link.springer.com/article/10.1198/108571102726

Answer (score 9):

Another difference between the two methods is described in Luke (2017):

> Both the Kenward-Roger (Kenward & Roger, 1997) and Satterthwaite (1941) approaches are used to estimate denominator degrees of freedom for F statistics or degrees of freedom for t statistics. SAS PROC MIXED uses the Satterthwaite approximation (SAS Institute, 2008). **While the Satterthwaite approximation can be applied to ML or REML models, the Kenward-Roger approximation is applied to REML models only.**
>   (my bold)

- Luke, S.G. (2017). Evaluating significance in linear mixed-effects models in R.  *Behavior Research Methods, 49:4*, 1494-1502. https://doi.org/10.3758/s13428-016-0809-y

Answer (score 0):

"This latest result uses the Satterthwaite method, which is implemented in the lmerTest package. Note that, with this method, not only are the degrees of freedom slightly different, but so are the standard errors. That is because the Kenward-Roger method also entails making a bias adjustment to the covariance matrix of the fixed effects"

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/sophisticated.html

This is about degrees of freedom in emmeans, but I think might be useful.

Comment: Not totally about df in emmeans. When K-R is selected, you also get the adjusted covariances.