# Why are the estimated denominator degrees of freedom differ so much between lme and lmer models?

Tags: r, mixed-model, anova, lme4-nlme

I want to run a linear mixed model (LMM) testing the effects of two continuous variables (FD and FI) over time (Year:FD, Year:FI) on my response variable (QMD). For LMMs I typically use lmer4 but as in this model the variance increases over time, I want to use nlme to weight the model variance by year (using VarIdent=Year). However, when I run the ANOVA table of the model, it seems something is not correct. The Denonminator degrees of freedom (DenDF) do not seem correct.

When I compare the estimated DenDF of lmer (lme4) and lme (nlme) models, they are very different. The other estimates vary also, but I assumed this was because, as I said before, in the lme model I weighted the variance by year. Do you know why the two models report so different DenDFs?

Here the lmer model without weighting the variance by year

```
mod_lmer <- lmer (QMD ~ FD*Year + FI*Year + (1|Block) + (1|Plot), data=QMD_data, REML=TRUE)
```

[image]

Now, running the lme model - following BenBolker's approach to include crossed random factors in lme models - [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643713/how-to-specify-different-random-effects-in-nlme-vs-lme4)

```
mod_lme = lme (QMD ~ FdisPC1 * Inv + CWM_PC1 * Inv,
                    random=list(Dummy = pdBlocked(list(pdIdent(~Plot-1),
                                                       pdIdent(~Block-1)))), 
                    data=QMD_data,
                    weights = varIdent(form = ~1 | Inv),method="REML",control =list(msMaxIter = 1000, msMaxEval = 1000))
```

[image]

Does someone know why the estimated DenDF are so different from each other? Also, I realized that when in lmer model the DenDF for FDisPC1 and CWM_PC1 are different than the rest of the variables (34), in lme model both have the same DenDF that the other effects (1591)

Comment: [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/147032/28500) explains the problems in determining the degrees of freedom associated with fixed effects of a mixed model. The `anova()` for the older `lme` function doesn't even try to take those problems into account. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/108161/28500) for approximations used in `lmer` models.